# Filtering with a Q object on an annotated QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-q

A mock testcase:

```
def testCount(self):
    qs = Test.objects.all()
    qs = qs.annotate(a_count=Count('a_items'), b_count=Count('b_items'))
    for item in qs:
        print 'a_count: %d, b_count: %d' % (item.a_count, item.b_count)
    qs1 = qs.filter(Q(a_count__gt=0))
    self.assertEquals(qs1.count(), 1)
    qs2 = qs.filter(Q(a_count__gt=0) | Q(b_count__gt=0))
    self.assertEquals(qs2.count(), 1)
```

Output:

```
a_count: 1, b_count: 0
a_count: 0, b_count: 0
...
FAIL: testCount 
    self.assertEquals(qs2.count(), 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1
```

Why does the | operator change the behavior like this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is still an [open issue](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11293) as of v1.2.4.

I guess you'd have test one of the supplied patches in the [bug report](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11293) or resort to [raw queries](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#adding-annotations) until it is officially fixed.